# is there anyway I can get information about vkimage?

Tags: vulkan

I have a VkImage, is there any way to get some part of the createInfo which used to create this image? For example, the arrayLayers, mipLevels, extent and format? It seems `vkGetImage*` does not have this functionality at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any information you might query about a `VkImage` is information which, at one point, you must have had because you gave it to Vulkan. Making a Vulkan driver implementation keep track of information you have is a waste of memory and a possible source of driver bugs. Therefore, Vulkan expects that, if you find some information about a `VkImage` to be important, then you will store that information alongside the image after its creation.

In general, Vulkan has no querying APIs for any information which you yourself provided for any object.